# Pandas: using iloc to retrieve data does not match input index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataset which contains contributor's id and contributor_message. I wanted to retrieve all samples with the same message, say, contributor_message == 'I support this proposal because...'.

I use data.loc[data.contributor_message == 'I support this proposal because...'].index -> so basically you can get the index in the DataFrame with the same message, say those indices are 1, 2, 50, 9350, 30678,...

Then I tried data.iloc[[1,2,50]] and this gives me correct answer, i.e. the indices matches with the DataFrame indices.

However, when I use data.iloc[9350] or higher indices, I will **NOT** get the corresponding DataFrame index. Say I got 15047 in the DataFrame this time.

Can anyone advise how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This occurs when your indices are not aligned with their integer location.

Note that [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is used to slice by index and [`pd.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is used to slice by integer location.

Below is a minimal example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 1, 1, 5]}, index=[0, 1, 2, 4, 5])

idx = df[df['A'] == 1].index

print(idx)  # Int64Index([0, 2, 4], dtype='int64')

res1 = df.loc[idx]
res2 = df.iloc[idx]

print(res1)
#    A
# 0  1
# 2  1
# 4  1

print(res2)
#    A
# 0  1
# 2  1
# 5  5
```

You have 2 options to resolve this problem.

**Option 1**

Use `pd.DataFrame.loc` to slice by index, as above.

**Option 2**

Reset index and use `pd.DataFrame.iloc`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
idx = df[df['A'] == 1].index

res2 = df.iloc[idx]

print(res2)
#    A
# 0  1
# 2  1
# 3  1
```